# Excel formula to search if all cells in a range read "True", if not, then show "False"

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, contains

Using an excel formula to search if all cells in a range read "True", if not, then show "False"

For example:

```
A      B     C     D
True  True  True   True
True  True  FALSE  True
```

I want a formula to read this range and show that in row 2, the was a "False" and since there are no falses in row 1 I want it to show "true."

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: just `=AND(A1:D1)`

Comment: That didn't work. I want it to look at columns A-D as the range and say "False" if any falses exist. I am using this as a check and have many columns so it would be nice instead of checking each column for falses that I could look in one column and identify the rows that did show a "false."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it appears you have the values as text, and not the numeric True/False, then you can use either `COUNTIF` or `SUMPRODUCT`

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:D2="False")),"False","True")
=IF(COUNTIF(A3:D3,"False*"),"False","True")
```

Comment: The COUNTIF formula worked! Thank you so much! I was writing the exact same formula but I didn't include the * after false. If you happen to read this, would you mind sharing why that symbol was needed? Thanks again!!

Comment: @user3384215, without the *, Excel translates `"False"` to the logical value, rather than keeping it as text. The `*` forces it into a string, which will then allow it to match the text in the cells. Note that the `*` will also mean it would match Falses, FalseStuff, and anything else that begins with those 5 letters

Answer (score 37):

You can just AND the results together if they are stored as TRUE / FALSE values:

```
=AND(A1:D2)
```

Or if stored as text, use an array formula - enter the below and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of Enter.

```
=AND(EXACT(A1:D2,"TRUE"))
```

Comment: My data is certainly 'native' TRUE/FALSE boolean values; so the straight AND(..) worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:D1,FALSE)>0,FALSE,TRUE)
```

(or you can specify any other range to look in)

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. I looked on one of my rows that I knew contained a false as a check and the formula you suggested return a true.

Comment: I think it may be because the cells contain text. That why I have been confused on getting this to work.

Comment: You can simplify this by just saying `=COUNTIF(A1:D1, FALSE)=0`

Answer (score 1):

```
=COUNTIFS(1:1,FALSE)=0
```

This will return TRUE or FALSE (Looks for FALSE, if count isn't 0 (all True) it will be false